# Android generate signed APK error somewhere

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

here is a problem. When I try to generate a signed APK this error shows up everytime

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/sun/activation/registries/LineTokenizer.class

Here is gradle which I use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lodka.lodkanadejeapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile ('com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-tasks';
}
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can you guys please give me a tip what is wrong? It is frustrating that you have finished a making of app and you can't generate an app :/

Thanks :)

Comment: Clean project. .

Comment: i think that 
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
and 
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.5'
have duplicate entry

Comment: Error is usually duplication. Aren't 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.5' and files('libs/mail.jar') the same library? If it is, remove one and rebuild

Comment: thanks it helped :))).... you guys are awesome

Comment: Before generate signed apk try to run project , if it showing some error then fix it otherwise will let u know. Try once it.

Comment: as shown in error java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/sun/activation/registries/LineTokenizer.class i think there is problem with compile files('libs/activation.jar') in gradle you have to remove it first and clean the project and again add this jar in lib folder to use.

Comment: Kailas Bhakade... of course in debug mode everything went good.. but when I was making signed APK it stopped on this exception